# clustering the node.js websocket server with pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, pm2

I try to load balancing the web socket server.

in my project, the clients in the same room must connect to same node.js process.

So i use the pm2 like this.

```js
[server]

// ports will be 7370 ~ 7373
let port = 7370 + parseInt(process.env.pm_id)

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}!`)
})

const wss = new WebSocketServer({ server: server, path: "/hello" })

wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
    ws.on('message', (data) => {
        console.log(` [ ${process.env.name}${process.env.pm_id} ] : ${data} `)
    })
})
```

```js
[client]

for(let i=0; i<100 ;i++){
    let ws = new WebSocket(`ws://127.0.0.1:${7370 + (i % 4)}/hello`)
    ws.on("open", (data) => {
        let index = i % 4
        console.log(index.toString())
        ws.send(index.toString())
    })
}
```

As a result of executing with the above code, it was confirmed that there was no problem with socket connection and communication.

I wonder if there will be no problem implementing websocket load balancing in this way.

open the websocket servers to other port for connect directly